# How know whether image is coming from cache or form url in SDWebImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` for loading a list of images and it was really good but while loading images next time it's loading image from cache if the url is same. But I need to know its coming form cache or web. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the cache to see if the image in question has already been downloaded like so:

```
NSString *key = [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] cacheKeyForURL:URL];
UIImage *image = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:key];
```

Answer (score 3):

Check SDWebImageManager, it has 2 versions of functions to check whether an URL is already cached or not:

```
- (BOOL)diskImageExistsForURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

There's also a version with a block which executes after the check. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

use your url

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:url];

if (cachedImage) 
{
   [button setImage:cachedImage];
   //image is cashed
}
else 
{
   [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
}
```

and then implement delegate function

```
- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage*)image {
   [button setImage:image];
   // new image
}
```